# Criteria, how to access a subclass property

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, criteria-api

weirdly I cannot find something simple about this, I've got 2 entity, one inside an other and my question is how can I access a property from the sub-entity?

entity 1

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class ObjectA{
    String name;
    String surname;
    ObjectB B;
}
```

entity 2

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
ObjectB{
    String family;
    String range;
}
```

what I want is to access familly and range with a criteria search, so I made this :

```
public List<ObjectA> search(String name, String surname, String family, String range) {
    Criteria c = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ObjectA.class, "a");

if (!name.equals("")) {
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("a.name", name));
}
if (!surname.equals("")) {
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("a.surname", surname));
}
if (!family.equals("")) {
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("a.B.family", family));
}
if (!range.equals("")) {
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("a.B.range", range));
}
return c.list();
```

}

name and surname can be accessed but family and range cannot.
'could not resolve property'
What should I do?

thanks =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create an alias for the subclass property to be able to access it.

Take a look at section 15.4 of the following manual http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: This doc is not useful :c (already looked at it).
They do indeed explain how to make aliases but they don't show the entity implementation.

what does kitten represent for example? is this the name of the subclass?

Comment: Kittens is a collection of elements mapped to Cat class. In your case it is something like:  if (!family.equals("")) { c.createAlias("B","B");
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("a.B.family", family));
}

Comment: thanks it helped, in the end, doing this works :
c.createAlias("a.B", "subB").add(Restrictions.eq("subB.family", family));

Answer (score 2):

In your case I'm not sure that you need aliases.
To request on a sub-entity, you need to create a criteria on the sub-entity, then add the parameters on it :

```
public List<ObjectA> search(String name, String surname, String family, String range) {
    Criteria aCriteria = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ObjectA.class);

if (!name.equals("")) {
    aCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name));
}
if (!surname.equals("")) {
    aCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("surname", surname));
}

Criteria bCriteria = aCriteria.createCriteria("B");

if (!family.equals("")) {
    bCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("family", family));
}
if (!range.equals("")) {
    bCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("range", range));
}
return aCriteria.list();
```

Beware : the `aCriteria.createCriteria("B")` will make it so that only `ObjectA` objects that have a non `null` B will be returned, so you might want to create the sub-criteria only if `family` and `range` are not empty.

Comment: that's basically just another way of creating the same thing. With createAlias() the code is cleaner IMHO

Comment: I tend to use aliases only when there is a need for a criteria between two different sub-entities. Mostly because I find the sub-criteria syntax simpler.

Comment: i strongly agree with sebastien  +1 for that